# How to attach onClick events to preview image in vue-dropzone-component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, dropzone

I have components dropzone on vue. Im install my template in settings.
Then i want to set v-on:click(method) to preview image in dropzone, but event don`t works. How to set correctly click to element?

```
<template>
     <vue-dropzone :options="dropzoneOptions" ref="myVueDropzone" id="customdropzone"
                   :preview-template="template">
     </vue-dropzone>
</template>

methods: {
     template () {
        return `<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview" v-on:click.native="alert(1)">
                    <div class="dz-image" v-on:click="alert(1)">
                        <img data-dz-thumbnail>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dz-details" v-on:click="alert(1)">
                        <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size></span></div>
                        <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
                        <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
                        <div class="dz-success-mark"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                        <div class="dz-error-mark"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
                    </div>`
            ;
        },
 }


data: function () {
    return {
        dropzoneOptions: {
            url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
            thumbnailWidth: 200,
            maxFilesize: 0.5,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            previewTemplate: this.template(),
            headers: {"My-Awesome-Header": "header value"},
        },
        salonID: 0,
        photos: [],
      }
    },
```

Comment: Share live demo or any fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xfsaap9h/

Comment: Trying to do the same thing. Did you figure this out?

Comment: any progress on this? im also having the same issue I have tried this 
https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/
and this creating the instance, but still the directives are not working, so frustrating